# Archivos, necesito crear un programa en C# que compare y devuelva resultados entre archivos

Tags: c#, archivo

soy estudiante de primer año en programación y me piden el siguiente ejercicio:
Debo crear un pequeño programa que, teniendo una base de datos en un archivo "tarjetas.txt" donde tiene los datos de 3 tarjetas (nroTarjeta, y saldo), debo generar un archivo "Consolidado.txt" donde se almacene lo siguiente:
el primer campo debe tener el nro de tarjeta
el segundo, contendrá la palabra SI o NO dependiendo si hay diferencia entre saldos
y el tercero el valor de dicha diferencia anteponiendo el signo + o - según corresponda.
Para realizar el test debo emular datos leidos desde la BD con los siguientes valores...y me da 3 valores.

Por el momento cree la clase Tarjeta con sus metodos:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace Archivo
{
    public class Tarjeta
    {
        public decimal Diferencia { get; set; }
        public List<int> NroTarjeta { get; set; }
        public List<int> SaldoConsolidado { get; set; }
        
        public Tarjeta()
        {
            Diferencia = new decimal();
            NroTarjeta = new List<int>();
            SaldoConsolidado = new List<int>();
            
        }
        public decimal CalcularDiferencia()
        {
            decimal resta = 0;
           
            foreach(var item in SaldoConsolidado)
            {
                resta -= item;
            }
            Diferencia = resta;

            decimal diff = this.CalcularDiferencia();
            string diffSigno = diff.ToString();
            if (diff < 0) diffSigno = "-" + diff;
            else diffSigno = "+" + diff;

            return Diferencia;
            
        }

        public string Resultado()
        {
        if (Diferencia > 0) return "SI";
                else return "NO";
        }
    }
}
```

Y en el programa principal ya no se que probar...no enuentro nada en youtube, bibliografia...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Archivo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //TextWriter archivo;
            //archivo = new StreamWriter("Registros.txt");

            //archivo.WriteLine("NroTarjeta;SaldoConsolidado", true);
            //archivo.WriteLine("1234;3500", true);
            //archivo.WriteLine("4321;5788", true);
            //archivo.WriteLine("9999;5500", true);

            //archivo.Close();


            string pathEntrada = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\TP2\Archivo\Archivo\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Tarjetas.txt";
            //string pathCalculo = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\TP2\Archivo\Archivo\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Registros.txt";
            //string pathSalida = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\TP2\Archivo\Archivo\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Consolidado.txt";
            List<Tarjeta> tarjet = new List<Tarjeta>();

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathEntrada))
            //using (StreamReader st = new StreamReader(pathCalculo))
            {
                string Encabezado = sr.ReadLine();
                string[] columnaEncabezado = Encabezado.Split(";");

                foreach (var dato in columnaEncabezado)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dato);
                }
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string linea = sr.ReadLine();
                    string[] columnas = linea.Split(";");
                }
                
            foreach(var dato in columnas)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dato);
            }
            }
            Tarjeta tarjeta = new Tarjeta();
            tarjeta.NroTarjeta = columnas[0].ToString();
            tarjeta.SaldoConsolidado.Add(int.Parse(columnas[1].ToString()));
            tarjeta.Resultado = columnas[2];
            tarjeta.Diferencia = columnas[3].ToString();

             

            


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Si alguien podría guiarme un poquito, o decirme donde investigar por favor.

Muchas gracias.
Saludos.

EDITO: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberias subir el contenido del archivo para ver como trabajarlo.

Comment: No agregues metodos en tus tarjetas dejalas como solo objeto, y crea una clase ServicioTarjetas este servicio tiene un metodo CompararSaldos con dos parametros tarjetaA y tarjetaB el resultado es una Enumaracion {mayor, menor, igual}

Comment: Reescribe tu clase Tarjeta con tres propiedades  string NumeroTarjeta, string Comercio, decimal Saldo

Comment: Realmente no me doy cuenta como armar la clase Serviciotarjetas, sigo en el mismo problema. No me termino de encaminar para hacer funcionar el programa.
De hecho la clase tarjeta era lo unico que no me generaba errores.

Comment: COmo sugerencia, indica qué problema tienes con el código cómo lo tienes. Nunca será evidente.

Comment: El problema me surge principalmente en el program.cs, cuando intento indexar los archivos, para que se lean y se comparen me da error.
En primera instancia me dice que "columnas" no existe en el contexto...y no he encontrado ni un solo tutorial de como indexar en C# (perdón que me falto la aclaración del problema, pense que quizás lo que estaba mal era mi codificación de todo el programa)

Comment: Pudiste resolver? Estoy con el mismo ejercicio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para practicar puedes usar https://dotnetfiddle.net

inicie un ejemplo para que puedas guiarte al principio, ya solo debes continuar
cualquier duda escribela, alguien de la comunidad podra ayudarte.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //crear tarjetas
        
        List<Tarjeta> tarjetas= new List<Tarjeta>();
        var tarjetaA= new Tarjeta();
        tarjetaA.NumeroTarjeta="00011";
        tarjetaA.Saldo=2;
        
        var tarjetaB= new Tarjeta();
        tarjetaB.NumeroTarjeta="00022";
        tarjetaB.Saldo=2;
        
        tarjetas.Add(tarjetaA);
        tarjetas.Add(tarjetaB);
        
        //pendiente llamado de la comparacion
        //pendiente muestra de resultados
    }
}

public class Tarjeta
{
   // cambio sugerido agregar un Constructor con Numero de tarjeta como parametro
   // para definirlo solamente al instanciar Tarjeta y hacer la propiedad como readonly el numero de tarjeta 
  public string NumeroTarjeta {get; set;}
      
  public decimal Saldo {get; set;}  
      
}

public enum ResultadoComparacion{
  Igual =0,
    Mayor=1,
    Menor
}

public class ServicioTarjeta
{
  public ResultadoComparacion CompararSaldoAconB(Tarjeta tarjetaA,Tarjeta tarjetaB)
  {
      if(tarjetaA.Saldo== tarjetaB.Saldo)
          return ResultadoComparacion.Igual;
       
      if(tarjetaA.Saldo>  tarjetaB.Saldo)
          return ResultadoComparacion.Mayor;
      
       
    return ResultadoComparacion.Menor;
  }
      


  public List<Tarjeta> CargarTajetas(string rutaArchivo)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException("Por implementar la carga de tarjetas desde ");
  }
      
}
```

Lo olvidaba ejercicio https://dotnetfiddle.net/S9xEOU